# What's Martini (the brand)?

Tags: cocktails, spirits

I'm a total novice, so excuses for what is likely a ridiculously stupid question.  I know that a MARTINI is a drink (like a gin martini, vodka martini) but there is also a bottled drink called "[MARTINI](https://www3.martini.com)", in many varieties (extra dry - torino, bianco, rosso, and so on). What's the relation between MARTINI-the-drink and MARTINI-the-brand?

I use MARTINI-the-brand to make Negronis, to mix with tonic, and so on, and these drinks are obviously not martinis, even though they're made with a drink which has the word MARTINI on the label.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Martini the brand is an Italian vermouth made by Martini & Rossi.

Traditionally, martini the drink is a concoction made with gin and vermouth, and a strong (but unproven) theory as to its etymology is that martini the drink was originally named after Martini the brand.